# Set tag referenced in code, storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I'm updated an iOS app I did not initially build, and the tags from the storyboard where somehow used which I'm not familiar with how to set - are used to identify buttons within a scrollview.  Could I get some help on how to setup in XCode 5 storyboards (if that is where it's set)?

```
     //Set fonts for button 1
for(UIButton *button in view1.subviews){
    if(button.tag == 1 || button.tag == 8 || button.tag == 13 || button.tag == 18){button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Cachet-Bold" size:20];}
    else{button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Cachet-Book" size:18];}
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The tag is a field under the view category in the preferences tab of the right pane of interface builder.

Comment: Actually, that would be the **Attributes Inspector** tab of the Utilities pane.

Comment: In my Xcode 5.0.2, the "View" section in the Attributes Inspector is empty when I select a UILabel in a "custom" style prototype cell, and even when I drag a label into a plain scrollview or similar. This is weird.

Comment: I've got the same issue in Xcode 5.0.2. Actually, I set the tags for a number of buttons (same version of Xcode), and needed to go back and check one. Now I can't find the field where they were set. What's up with that?

Comment: @fbitterlich--please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22523751/cant-find-field-to-check-or-set-uibutton-tag-xcode-5-0/22523884?noredirect=1#22523884

Answer (score 11):

**View** > **Utilities** > **Attribute inspector** and under **View** set tag there.

Another is

**View** > **Utilities** > **Identity inspector** like:

[image]