# Can't find field to check or set UIButton tag--Xcode 5.0

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

I've got a number of buttons in a view and have assigned a tag number to each for identification in code. I just went back to check one of them, and can't find the field in the Attributes Inspector where I originally assigned the tags. I've tried all my buttons and restarted Xcode, and the result is the same--no tag field.

Here's what my attribute inspector looks like with a (tagged) button selected in the storyboard:

[image]

I came upon a recent comment by someone who also couldn't locate the tag field. He also is using Xcode 5.0.2.

Anybody else run into this?

Thanks!

Comment: if you roll over the word "View", does the word "show" appear over at the right edge of that line?

Comment: I'll be damned. Yep. Please put your suggestion in an answer and I'll green-check it and up vote it. May seem a small thing, but I'll bet I'm not the first to have been caught out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sections in the attributes inspector can be shown or hidden by clicking on the lines where the words "View", "Control", etc appear. When you rollover the line with these section titles, you'll see the words "show" or "hide" appear on the right edge of the line. Clicking anywhere on the line toggles between the two states.

Answer (score 0):

Where it says view: Move your mouse over to the far right and something should appear that says "Show". Click on it and you'll see the tag identifiers, etc.